# How to fix product image upload in Magento 1.4.1.1?

Tags: magento-1.7

I am facing issue while uploading the product images in **Magento ver. 1.4.1.1** from admin. When I try to upload the image I do not get any error but the images are not visible in the front end as well as in the admin section of Magento.

I am able to see the message like following screenshot.
[image: screenshot]

I have following folder created

```
/media/tmp/catalog/product
```

Under this folder the images are visible.

The issue is happening on windows 7, xampp server.
On my Linux environment it is working fine.

Please help me to fix the issue.